# Non exhaustive search error in SML n-ary tree

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to code in SML and facing the problem listed below 
I have made a N-Ary tree and the variable tr stores the value of tree created.

`val tr =node([leaf "x", node([leaf "y", leaf "x" , leaf "z"])]);`

The function cat is what I hoped will print the values of all the leaf nodes.
But I get a non-exhaustive search warning, and it does not work.

`fun cat (node ( [node t1 , node t2])) = cat(node t1) ^" "^cat(node t2)
    | cat ( node ([leaf x, node t1])) = x ^" "^cat(node t1)
    | cat( leaf x) = x`

Here is my data structure for the n-ary tree

`datatype 
    'a ntree = leaf of 'a | node of 'a ntree list;`

The error is get is as follows

```
 `val tr = node [leaf "x",node [leaf "y",leaf "x",leaf "z"]] : string ntree
 .\printValues.sml:14.5-16.20 Warning: match nonexhaustive
      node (node t1 :: node t2 :: nil) => ...
      node (leaf x :: node t1 :: nil) => ...
      leaf x => ...

  val cat = fn : string ntree -> string
  - cat(tr);

  uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
   raised at: .\printValues.sml:16.20`
  `
```

How can i solve this ? Rather, please point in the direction of how to go on to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing definitions for `cat (node xs)` where `xs` have fewer than 2 elements.

The `node` pattern is just a list under the hood -- so you should follow the basic SML pattern of defining a function on lists by providing a definition for the empty list and then for patterns that look like `x::xs`. In your case you would probably want to handle patterns that look like `node [x]` separately, so as not to have any stray space at the end. The following works:

```
fun cat (leaf x) = x
|   cat (node []) = ""
|   cat (node [x]) = cat x
|   cat (node (x::xs)) = cat x ^ " " ^ cat (node xs);
```

I moved the `leaf x` pattern up -- since to me that is a basis case and by convention basis cases are listed first. A feature of your tree definition is that it allows for non-branching parent nodes. For example,

```
node[node[leaf "x"]]
```

is perfectly valid. The case `cat (node [x]) = cat x` is designed to strip away those somewhat pointless intermediate nodes. A subtly in the final clause is that if `xs` is a list of trees then it is not itself a tree, so it must be wrapped in the `node` constructor before being fed to `cat`.

SML isn't exactly batteries included -- but the [Standard ML Basis Library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/) has some goodies. There is a `String.concatWith` which is a `join` function. If you can use it then there is a slick way to write what you want:

```
fun cat (leaf x) = x
|   cat (node branches) = String.concatWith " " (map cat branches);
```

With output for your sample:

```
cat tr;
val it = "x y x z" : string
```

The first approach can be thought of as defining something like `concatWith` with a hard-wired delimiter (" ") and in the special case of the node list in your tree data type.

Comment: could you post full code here ? I am not able to get what is to be written for the first definition here.

Comment: @CyprUS I thought that it might be homework so I didn't give the full code. I edited it to fill in the details.

Comment: @CyprUS Curiousity is good :) Your rep is too high for you to be the sort of person who asks for someone to do their homework for them, but the way you ended the question suggested to me that maybe you were asking for a homework hint. When you asked for the details in the comments I was pretty confident that it wasn't homework.

Comment: I just wish I had figured it out myself. There is not much literature to properly guide people on such tricky questions, hence I relied on SO. Plus there are no debuggers for SML, which makes lives harder when complex data structures are involved

Comment: Non-academic work in ML should probably be done in the dialects Ocaml or F# because they have more tools and more current books. In SML I haven't had quite the same need for a debugger as in other languages but doubtless it could come in handy. I haven't used it yet, but PolyML (which is a full implementation of SML + some extensions) boasts a debugger. See http://www.polyml.org/